# character encoding in java web project

Tags: java, character, encode, webproject

I just get a strange encoding problem in java web project.

```
System.out.println("search url: " + searchURL);    
searchURL = new String(searchURL.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
System.out.println("test===" + new String(searchURL.getBytes("utf-8")));
```

---

I test the code above in java main function, and in chinese character it works all right.

```
output:
search url: https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27机器 猫%27&$format=json&$skip=0

test===https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27机器 猫%27&$format=json&$skip=0
```

---

But when runs this code in tomcat.

```
output:
search url: https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27机器 猫%27&$format=json&$skip=0

test===https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27鏈哄櫒 鐚?27&$format=json&$skip=0
```

then i test this in tomcat:

```
searchURL = new String(searchURL.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
System.out.println(new String(searchURL.getBytes("gbk"));
System.out.println(new String(searchURL.getBytes("gb2312"));
```

both above is ok. so why ?
Any suggestion will be appreciated, really thx !

Comment: What were you expecting to happen on your last example? Both GBK and GB2312 are valid character encodings.

Comment: Where did the searchURL come from ? Is it obtained in the Servlet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default charset will be different between your jvm and the tomcat jvm

try

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

this will use the default charset to encode the string which may or may not be utf-8

```
System.out.println("test===" + new String(searchURL.getBytes("utf-8")));
```

so while the byte array is utf-8 the decoder may expect something else.

Comment: searchURL = new String(searchURL.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8"); by this,  doesn't it changes the searchURL to utf-8 format?

Comment: @santi: I have added a clarification

Comment: @santi: java strings are always `utf-16`. The byte array produced by getBytes will be `utf-8` but once it gets made into a `String` it will be decoded back to `utf-16` using the specified charset.

Comment: You are right, really thanks. But i have set the tomcat server,xml.  <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>

Comment: How can i change the default characterSet in tomcat ? I am new to tomcat , my apologize

Comment: try `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` for starting up tomcat. Not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: Actually, my question is that the same url connection request when i send it in the java main function, the bing sarch api return correctly. but in tomcat it Garbled. so i think it must be the reason as characterset is not the utf-8 in tomcat.   System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); return utf-8 in java main. but return gbk in tomcat.